# "fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined"

Tags: c, linker, visual-studio-2005

I'm very new with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. I'm writing a sequence search program, when I try to compile it using MS VS 2005, I get an error:

> fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int search (int A[], int len, int no)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        if (A[i] == no) return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the starting function `int main()`.

Answer (score 2):

`int main()` should be added:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int search (int A[], int no)
{
    int i;
    // added sizeof to determine length of array instead of sending the length to function
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(A); i++)
        if (A[i] == no) return i;

    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int item = search(a, 3);

    if (item > 0) {
        printf("%d\n", item);
    }
    else {
        printf("Element not found!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```